# ASPNET Account Password

Tags: windows-server-2003, asp.net, .net

I have a Windows Server 2003 box with .Net Framework 2.0. I had the ASPNET account password set manually (done in the machine.config). Recently it was upgraded to .Net Framework 3.5. Apparently the upgrade rewrote the machine.config and I had to redo the password. However, seemingly randomly, the account password will change. The machine.config still has the manual password, so I'm not sure why it's doing this. Any help ould be appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, I am able to go into Computer Management -> Users -> And set the password. Also, the password is still in the machine.config.

Comment: Why are you setting this? If you just ensure that local and remote logins aren't allowed on the account, and you don't have any file security set on these accounts via FTP or other remote services, you really shouldn't need explicit passwords set for it. Yes, it's more secure if you do, but over complicating security _sometimes_ isn't worth it.

Comment: Originally it was caused by an accident. I was working on a laptop with a touchpad and was trying to reset an account password. The account was right below the ASPNET account so I set that one instead (in Local Users and Groups). I haven't been able to figure out how to make the machine.config have the autogenerate password and set it to do that in the Local Users and Groups.